# Adding SocialAuthenticationFilter using SpringSocialConfigurer via XML for enabling sign in through social providers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I am trying to use spring social 1.1.4 for implementing social provider sign-ins.

In the docs, [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-socialauthenticationfilter-code) we can configure SocialAuthenticationFilter through SpringSocialConfigurer. The example here is for Java Configuration.

However, due to some restriction of using existing framework which is based on XML config, I need to implement the above using XML configuration only.

How can I inject this SpringSocialConfigurer in spring security config xml. I mean, should I use

```
<sec:custom-filter ...>
```

or

```
<sec:http ...>
```

or anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to security configuration:

```
 <!-- Adds social authentication filter to the Spring Security filter chain. -->
        <security:custom-filter ref="socialAuthenticationFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
```

And add bean:

```
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userIdSource"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="usersConnectionRepository"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>
</bean>
```